# Failed to accept an incoming connection: connection from "9.42.x.x" rejected, allowed hosts: "zabbix-server"

Tags: kubernetes, containers, openshift, zabbix

SUMMARY

I have installed zabbix on OpenShift cluster. I am trying to monitor a host(vm) outside the cluster but the zabbix server is unable to connect to it. In the `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf` file I have mentioned the DNS name of the server `zabbix-server` but it looks like there server is trying to connect through a different public IP. I am not sure what this IP is.

OS / ENVIRONMENT / Used docker-compose files

I applied the kubernetes.yaml file present in this repo - https://github.com/zabbix/zabbix-docker/blob/6.2/kubernetes.yaml - on an OpenShift cluster.

CONFIGURATION

In the `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf` file Server=zabbix-server.

STEPS TO REPRODUCE

Apply the kubernetes.yaml file on Openshift cluster and try to monitor any external vm.

EXPECTED RESULTS

The zabbix server should be able to connect to the vm.

ACTUAL RESULTS

Zabbix server logs.

```
Defaulted container "zabbix-server" out of: zabbix-server, zabbix-snmptraps
\*\* Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "DBHost": 'mysql-server'...added
287:20230120:060843.131 Zabbix agent item "system.cpu.load\[all,avg5\]" on host "Host-C" failed: first network error, wait for 15 seconds
289:20230120:060858.592 Zabbix agent item "system.cpu.num" on host "Host-C" failed: another network error, wait for 15 seconds
289:20230120:060913.843 Zabbix agent item "system.sw.arch" on host "Host-C" failed: another network error, wait for 15 seconds
289:20230120:060929.095 temporarily disabling Zabbix agent checks on host "Host-C": interface unavailable
```

Logs from the agent installed on the vm.

```
350446:20230122:103232.230 failed to accept an incoming connection: connection from "9.x.x.219" rejected, allowed hosts: "zabbix-server"
350444:20230122:103332.525 failed to accept an incoming connection: connection from "9.x.x.219" rejected, allowed hosts: "zabbix-server"
350445:20230122:103432.819 failed to accept an incoming connection: connection from "9.x.x.210" rejected, allowed hosts: "zabbix-server"
350446:20230122:103533.114 failed to accept an incoming connection: connection from "9.x.x.217" rejected, allowed hosts: "zabbix-server"
```

If I add this IP in `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf` it will work. But what IP is this? Is this a service? Or any node/pod IP? It keeps on changing. Everytime I cannot change this id in the conf file. I need something more stable.

Kindly help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know zabbix. So I have to make some educated guesses both in how the agent works and how the server works.

But, to summarize, unlike something like docker compose where you are running the zabbix server on a known server, in Openshift/Kubernetes you are deploying into a cluster of machines with their own networking. In other words, the whole point of OpenShift is that OpenShift will control where the application's pod gets deployed and will relocate/restart that pod as needed. With a different IP every time. (And the DNS name is meaningless since the two systems aren't sharing DNS anyway.) Most likely the IP's you are seeing are the pod's randomly assigned IPs.

So, what are you to do when you have a situation like yours where an external application requires a predicable IP? Well, option 1, is to remove that requirement. Using something like a certificate is obviously more secure and more reliable than depending on an IP anyway. But another option is to use an [egress IP](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.12/networking/openshift_sdn/assigning-egress-ips.html). This is a feature of OpenShift where you essentially use a proxy to provide an external application with a consistent IP.

Answer (score 0):

here im getting the similar error, plus im getting a lot of alerts because the zabbix servers reaches a timeout, I've seen when this happens the "Zabbix Queue" is very high. Maybe i think the zabbix monitoring gets too many values per second.